# make color cell in csv file for Excel

Tags: excel, csv

I am generating csv file for importing into Excel. Excel has no previous formatting.

a) Is there any markup to add color definition to a cell in csv ?

If not possible in csv, then in which Excel-import format(s) can I do (a) and (b),
formats that are preferably ascii-based, and easy to generate ?

b) Can I add column widths definitions to csv columns ?

Answer (score 17):

No and No! CSV files are basically raw cell data, with no formatting at all.

- Office Open XML — for Excel 2007 and above
- Excel 2003 XML — for Excel 2003 and above
- HTML — not really a good option, Excel is a bit ornery in its interpretation of HTML
- Sylk (.slk)
- Open Document Format (.ods) — can be read by Excel 2010.

Comment: @BSalita - I don't believe that colorif() is a valid Excel formula function, so why would you expect this to work in Excel? Instead, use conditional formatting for this type of task. - and with 347 reputation, you should know the correct way to ask a question on SO, and it isn't by adding a comment to an aswer of an unrelated question

Comment: You can use Excel formulas in CSV (or at least =HYPERLINK("someurl") is working for me). 

Whether you should is another matter.

edit: I see this is about formatting, not formulas. Ignore me