# How to dump data in to Excel file beyond its limitation?

Tags: c#, excel, xlsx, excel-interop

I have more than 2 million rows of data and I want to dump this data in Excel file but as given in this [specification](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3?CorrelationId=f746d6c5-5315-4d41-8d5d-74a0b998a190&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HP010342495) that Excel file can contains only **1,048,576 rows**.

Consider that I have 40 million rows in the database and I want to dump this data in excel file.

I did 1 test but got the same result that is successfully got **1,048,576 rows** and after that got error:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC Error

Code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 1200000; i++)
            {
                oSheet.Cells[i, 1] = i;
            }
```

I think of CSV file but I can't use it as because we cant give colors and styles to CSV file as per this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066511/write-csv-file-with-color-code) and my Excel file is going to contain many colors and styles.

Is there any third party tool or whatever through which I can dump more than 2 millions rows in Excel file? I am not concerned if it is paid or free.

Answer (score 3):

Like you said the current excel specification [Link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-ca36e2dc-1f09-4620-b726-67c00b05040f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) has a maximum of 1,048,576 rows. But the amount of Sheets is only limited by the memory.

Maybe the seperation of the content on multiple sheets would be a solution for this.

or if you want to do some analysis on the data for instance you could maybe aggregat the information before loading them into the excel file.