# Color CSV Column in Django Python

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to color a row with i am outputting. How can i add properties to that row. Like i want to color that row. How can i add color to that row in csv file. How can add properties like center, bold.

```
import csv
from django.http import HttpResponse

def GenerateCompanyCSV(request):
    # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate CSV header.
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="Company_Report-%s.csv"' % datetime.date.today()

    query_set = Company.objects.exclude(id=1).exclude(
                            company_is_deleted=True
                            ).annotate(
                            number_of_company_users=Count('userprofile')
                        ) 

    output = []

    for query in query_set:
        output.append([
            query.company_name, 
            query.company_email, 
            query.number_of_company_users, 
            query.company_created, 
            query.company_monthly_payment, 
            query.company_tab_opts, 
            query.company_status, 
            ])

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    # Output Color for this row
    writer.writerow(['Company Name', 'Company Email', 'Count Of Total Users', 'Created Date', 'Current Monthly Payment', 'Is TABopts Customer', 'Status'])
    #CSV Data
    writer.writerows(output)

    return response
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write csv file with color code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066511/write-csv-file-with-color-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV can't do that.

You need a rich table format like the one that [open office is using](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python-Calc)

Or the one that [excel is using](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)