# get color in field name while exporting csv file from mysql

Tags: mysql

is there other way to get colored csv file by exporting from mysql.

I want to make yellow color to all field. so it can be viewd in csv file as well.

Comment: No CSV is plain text as far as I know. csv stands for comma separated values. If you would import into for example  excel you could make a standard

Comment: i show people make color the mysql table's field

Comment: Your title suggest that you want to export something from mysql to a plain text file (CSV). You could create a field in your table called col our with a field value yellow. But if you open the file the text will not become yellow.

Comment: Not sure about your comment wrt mysql, I think your are referring to phpMyAdmin. The color might change if you select something. You can make a selection before you export or make the selection when you import the data in another program.

Comment: Is your question solved? Or do you mean you want to add yellow to the name of the column. For example name_yellow?!?!

Comment: my main purpose is to get colored csv file only.

Comment: how to get colored csv file?

Comment: CSV file has no color. See for a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716069/make-color-cell-in-csv-file-for-excel

Comment: Could you accept my question below?

Answer (score 0):

A CSV (Comma-separated value) file is a plain text file without formatting options.

See for a duplicate questions: [make color cell in csv file for Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716069/make-color-cell-in-csv-file-for-excel); [Write csv file with color code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066511/write-csv-file-with-color-code).

Good luck with you project.